# iOS capture event when youtube video ends or Done button pressed

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch

I am displaying a youtube video on a uiwebview. When user selects it, fullscreen video starts as normal. Which event is fired when video ends or "done" button is pressed? I read some posts about it but suggested methods are now deprecated. View event will also be useful, for example if viewDidAppear is fired when video ends, but is not. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement your video to play inside `MPMoviePlayerController` if you can and then try below. Or else you could try below directly (but i havnt tested without implementing `MPMoviePlayerController`)
**MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification** notification for `MPMoviePlayerController` as

Link :  http://www.devx.com/wireless/Article/44642/1954