# After playing a youtube-video in an UIWebView, the app restarts

Tags: ios, uiwebview, youtube, youtube-api

i'm using the following code, so load a Youtube video in my UIWebView (Outlet):

```
NSString *videoUrl = [self getVideoURL];
NSString *htmlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<html><head><meta name = \"viewport\" content = \"initial-scale = 1.0, user-scalable = no, width = 280\"/></head><body style=\"background:#F00;margin-top:0px;margin-left:0px\"><div><object width=\"280\" height=\"156\"><param name=\"movie\" value=\"%@\"></param><param name=\"wmode\" value=\"transparent\"></param><embed src=\"%@\" type=\"application/x-shockwave-flash\" wmode=\"transparent\" width=\"280\" height=\"156\"></embed></object></div></body></html>",videoUrl,videoUrl]    ;


[videoView loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.youtube.com"]];
```

all this works fine. but after watching the video and tapping on "done", my app starts new from beginning... but i don't understand why.
hope someone can give me a hint why this is happening?

Comment: What do you mean by "starts from the beginning"? You'll need to explain a bit more about how your app is architected rather than just saying that.

Comment: i'm guessing the app is crashing. what does the crash log say ?

Comment: it's not easy to describe.. the app is not crashing after touching "done". but it looks like opening the app - and i get the first view after starting the app and not the one who opened the youtube video.. hope my problem is now clearer? the console is empty - but the crash log file is really big.. look at http://s.c-m-d.info/L2sMHl

Comment: check out for memory leak and paste application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: function

Answer (score 0):

ok I found my mistake:
the "bug" is at the youtube player. After pressing "done", it returns to my rootView Controller. In my case, this is the really first view of the app.
I solved this by setting my ModalView as my rootViewController after presenting it.

Comment: also see this [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10554553/ios-capture-event-when-youtube-video-ends-or-done-button-pressed)